# Black screen in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, ios-simulator, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to launch a titanium app in the iOS simulator, but I get a black screen. Everything worked fine until now. I don't know why it doesn't work anymore.

This is the error I get:

```
[TRACE] ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
[INFO]  Finished building the application in 14s 136ms
[INFO]  Running application in iOS Simulator
[DEBUG] Terminating all iOS simulators
[INFO]  Launching application in iOS Simulator    
[DEBUG] Simulator command: "/Users/carl/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.3.0/iphone/ios-sim" launch /Users/carl/Dev/test/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app" --xcode-dir "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --sdk 7.1 --family iphone --retina --tall  
[INFO]  Focusing the iOS Simulator 
[ERROR] Project failed to build after 1m 44s 479ms
```

I tried to reset content and settings in the simulator, but it doesn't work. Also tried to reboot, and reinstall Xcode, with no luck.

The project launches correctly on a device.
I use Titanium SDK 3.3.0, Xcode 5.1.1, iOS SDK 7.1 on OSX 10.9.4 (Mavericks)

Comment: If you try to launch the app from the simulator's home screen, does it work?

Comment: Clean the build folder in xcode

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don't have the app installed on the simulator

Comment: @Woodstock I already tried, it didn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tmux causes the simulator to timeout.  See [this discussion](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160718/black-screen-on-ios-simulator).

Comment: yes, is there any relation between tmux and the error ?

Comment: I can't remember, I've had so many issues with Titanium I've lost track.  Try detaching from your tmux session and building again.

Comment: wtf, you're right, it works when I'm not using tmux, do you know why ? Please update your answer with this solution

Answer (score 0):

ios-sim isn't a supported mechanism for interacting with the iOS Simualtor.  I suggest you upgrade to Xcode 6 which includes CoreSimulator and the simctl command line tool to control it.  That should pretty much cover all of the main cases that you were using ios-sim for.

If you still have issues, please take a spindump and also look at the ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID]/system.log file to see what the current activity is on your device.